# Binary Search Trees when compared to sorted linked lists

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

if we have our elements in a sorted circular double linked list the order of operations (insert delete Max Min successor predecessor) are the same or even better than the binary search tree . so why we use them ?

is it because data structure authors want to familiarize reader with general concept of tree as a data structure with some simple examples ?

i have read some same questions but the questions were (inconsiderately !) asked with arrays instead of linked lists and answers were not useful for linked lists! since most of them addressed the problem of shifting the elements in the array for insertion.

Comment: How efficient is search in a balanced binary search tree?  In a linked list (sorted or not)?

Comment: search is :  tree = sorted List = O(lg(n))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the binary search in double circular linked list cannot be done since in a binary search we need the middle element but we cannot access the middle element in a linked list unless we pay theta(n/2) and so on ( half of the first half (1/4) or half of the second half (3/4) ) .

but the idea of making a binary search tree  stems from this idea.we almost keep the middle of each part of our data to use it for searching and other ends .

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is not "addressable", in a sense that, if you want to access the element in the middle of the list, for example to do binary search, you will have to walk the list.  That is to say the performance of list.get(index) is O(n).  If you back it up with any data structure that gives you O(1) performance, it will be an array in the end.  Then we will be back to the problem of allocating extra space and shifting the elements, which is not as efficient as binary search trees.

Comment: performance of tree.get(index) is also O(n).  and how it would become an array and would have the allocate problem ? can you explain more ?

Comment: Assuming a balanced BST, root is the middle of all the elements and you don't need to walk to it -- it is the starting point of the tree.

Comment: Now let's look at an array. It is addressable because it is a continuous chunk of memory. You get O(1) complexity to get to the nth element because the address can be computed in one step: address of the nth element is the address of the array plus n times the size of the pointer. You pay a penalty for being able to do this. It is not dynamic. It has to be allocated beforehand. You have to know the size of the collection beforehand.

Comment: The usual trick to hide the problem from the users of the array is to allocate some extra space and, when approaching the limit, allocate a bigger array and copy over all the elements. This trick sometimes can be expensive.  I have witnessed in my career Java's ArrayList was abused like such in a loop and caused the app to crash.

Comment: but you did not mentioned for example if you want to access the Max in a balanced binary search tree it would be O(log(n)) (and it is also the case for Min) but the doubly circular linked list can access them in O(1) .  and i was only talking about operations mentioned above . if you want to access the elements in the middle of an array list often you can simply have a pointer for that !. i mean the link list is doing the same job (maybe even better) with less complexity in coding !

Comment: Well if you do binary search, just one pointer to the element in the middle is not enough. When you recurse down, you will need more pointers and then we will be really looking at a tree.  Even with just min() and max() operations, the cost is associated with updating the collection; otherwise, I could just use two pointers to keep track of the min and the max. No need to know the entire collection. But if you want to keep the entire collection, you will have to walk the list to update it. Again, we are looking at O(n).